# Program crashes at the end of this function

Tags: c#

```
void student_info(char *name, int *hw1, int *hw2, int *hw3, int *ex1, int *ex2)
{
    printf("Please enter the student's name:\n");
    gets_s(name, 20);

    printf("\nPlease enter the student's homework grades:\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", & (*hw1), & (*hw2), & (*hw3) );

    printf("\nPlease enter the student's exam scores:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", & (*ex1) , & (*ex2) );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's c#?

Comment: This doesn't look like C#...

Comment: It looks like **C** or **C++**, not **C#**

Comment: It is definitely C or C++ and the reason for crash is probably wrong use of functions that cause (most probably) stack overwrite. Try to search how to use `scanf` function.

Comment: tips on writing a good question; 1) "crashes" tells us nothing much; how? what *exactly* happens? 2) what have you done to debug it? have you stepped through? where exactly does it happen? 3) use correct tags; while that *can be compiled* in C#, it is **very unlikely** that you're actually using C# here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Also, please tag it with the correct language.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, based on the code you've posted, that code is C, not C#. It could be C++, provided you're using it in "C" style.

Second, &* is nothing. If you access the object (object in the broader sesen of the term) in memory through a pointer with '*', and then get a pointer to the object accessed previously... you are doing basically nothing. Probably the confusion comes from the fact that variables in `scanf()` are usually preceded by a '&', but this is not needed if you are already passing a pointer.

Finally, there is not enough information to be able to assess why the program crashes. You're passing six pointers to this function, and maybe one of them points to invalid memory (memory not reserved previously or not belonging to an existing object).

This is a correct way to invoke the function:

```
char name[80];
int hw1;
int hw2;
int hw3;
int ex1;
int ex2;
student_info(name, &hw1, &hw2, &hw3, &ex1, &ex2);
```

This is an incorrect way to invoke the function:

```
char * name;
int * hw1;
int * hw2;
int * hw3;
int * ex1;
int * ex2;
student_info(name, hw1, hw2, hw3, ex1, ex2);
```

There are multiple possibilities here, too many to be able to go further.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to fix it if i show you my whole program? I'm invoking the function correctly, as far as im aware

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Just create a new program with the smallest set of instructions that reproduce the same error, and edit your question.